# Editing code-heavy answers doesn't always work

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, code-formatting

Let's say I'm editing some poor sod's code that is unformatted, and is almost the entire question. I format the code, I add in the error message that was copy-pasted into the title, I fix the grammar, etc, and I go to submit:

[image]

I get the "post is mostly code" warning. But I can't add more details, I'm just a lowly editor. However, it would dramatically improve the question for the code to be formatted, and for the error to be added in - I swear the edit's good!

How can I handle this? Is there an already accepted method? Better yet - can this be changed, so that this only appears for the OP, not for the editor?

(Note: I tried using an HTML comment and just adding a bunch of lorum ipsum - no dice. Seems that pops up regardless. I ended up adding some notes on parts of the code I could understand.)

Comment: +1 I've had this issue before too. Though not recently, I believe you'll stop having this issue when your edits don't have to be community approved (E.G 2k rep)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton unfortunately for me, that's 1500 rep off for me on SO =/

Comment: Yeah :/ I suppose the answer would be to avoid these questions at all costs until then (Until you have the rep required). They should probably usually be closed anyways. Rep wise, you are definitely better of attempting to answer questions rather than edit them.

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid attempting to salvage such a question.

Even once beautified it's unlikely to be a good fit for the site.

During your pre-2k reputation days (after which you can make any edit you like but you don't get a reputation reward), stick to edits where the contribution you make is unambiguous.

Answering questions well is a great way to earn reputation, but a far greater benefit to you will be the gains in subject knowledge that you'll acquire. That's worked for me.

Comment: It's not like the error wasn't in there - it was answerable.

Comment: Anyway, I'm quite happy to gain rep/knowledge, I'm just not a ninja like most answerers seem to be.

Comment: @heather: Now now, we're a lovely bunch of folk!

Comment: Not arguing that =) Just a lot better at programming.

Comment: @heather I think users above a certain rep limit are exempt from the particular filter you hit - while you're under it, so you can't submit it.